# Applying an IF condition in multiple columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have an ascii file as following (a sample)

```
id lon lat val1 val2 val3
1 22 38 67 66 87 89 
2 23.5 39 56 10 90 98
3 22.5 38.5 34 45 56 78
```

For specific points (lat,lon) I want to set to zero the variables val1, val2,val3.
e.g. for lon=22, lat=38 and lon=23.5,lat=39

i tried the following (only for val1 modification) and I got ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
How I could do that (setting also to 0 all the variables val)

```
import pandas as pd
col_names=['id','lon','lat','val1','val2','val3']
df = pd.read_csv(i,sep='\s+',names=col_names,header=None) 
df.loc[df['Lon'] ==22 and df['Lat'] ==38, 'val1'] = 0
```

Comment: `and` is invalid to compare Series, you need the bitwise operator `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple columns that start with `val` to process at a step, you can use [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter the columns and set it into a list `cols`.  Then, use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to set the selected columns, as follows:

```
# put all columns that start with `val` into a list
cols = df.filter(regex='^val').columns

# set 0 all the variables val*
df.loc[(df['Lon'] == 22) & (df['Lat'] == 38), cols] = 0
```

Comment: thank you, what if I would like to multiply by a factor the cols? Do I have to use df.loc[(df['Lon'] == 22) & (df['Lat'] == 38), cols] = cols * factor ?

Comment: @Nat  Use `df.loc[(df['Lon'] == 22) & (df['Lat'] == 38), cols] *= factor`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding brackets.

```
df.loc[(df['Lon'] ==22) & (df['Lat'] ==38), 'val1'] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
df['Lon'] ==22 and df['Lat'] ==38
```

use

```
(df['Lon'] ==22) & (df['Lat'] ==38)
```

Comment: Thank you. However , how I could set all variables to zero? e.g. val1,val2,val3? Do I have to do the same for other variables? Is there any other simple way? Since the original file has 24 variables

Comment: How I could use apply in that case?